# check if user is registered with facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have created simple facebook registration page. Is there any way to check if user is registered using javascript ?

Here is my registration page :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : 'http://xxxxxxxxxx', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={xxxxxxxx}&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration 
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
  redirect-uri="http://xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  width="530">
</fb:registration>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, when you load the javascript SDK add this line

```
});

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(userStatus);
  };
```

Now at the bottom of your file add this:

```
<script>
        function userStatus(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
              //the user is logged in on facebook and has already authorized your app
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              //the user is logged in on facebook but hasn't authorized your app
            } else {
              //the user is not logged in on facebook so we don't know if he has granted permission to your app
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio very much indeed .